# Alignment of Segmented Teeth along curve and Animation

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, transforms

I am working on a small project that involves drawing a curve over a set of misaligned teeth then transforming/ aligning them accurately along a curve that is drawn over the teeth as a guide to their optimal final position. So far I have only managed to segment the teeth but having a challenge tracing the curve over the teeth from a reference image then moving the teeth to their final position. After the above task I would like to animate the object showing the movement.

This is a screen shot of the intended setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Below is a video of the intended result:
https://youtu.be/XPgm0JDAGQc

Comment: Please be more specific: what part of the project you need help with? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png).

Comment: Have I addressed your question?

Comment: Basically, I import an stl file of crooked teeth, segment each individual tooth, then align each tooth along an ideal curve using a reference image that I can import into blender. After all the changes, I would like to create an animation of the teeth showing how they looked before being aligned then how they look after the alignment.

Comment: Is the issue with getting the curve to render, or are you having issues getting the teeth to move? You would probably need to make an armature/rig to move the teeth. You want to create a nurbs curve and adjust the bevel depth to have the curve so you can render it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use shapekeys like your reference video?=

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/12144ebb17030f82e562d93c9375679120190521171639/c55ccfb744135dae58866bacfa76743c20190521171639/1a49c0?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email

Comment: I have attached the exact blend file of the crooked teeth that I am working on. I have already segmented the individual teeth, so kindly download it and let me know the steps to follow to achieve a similar final result. Thanks for the responses.